# MongoDB Compass app does not have $search Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-compass

I am using MongoDB Compass app in Mac which is connected to my localhost database. I am not able to see `$search` Aggregation in the list of all available aggregations. Not sure if this is due to the MongoDB Version.

DB Info that I am using:

```
HOST: localhost:27017
CLUSTER: Standalone
EDITION: MongoDB 4.4.3 Community
```

[Missing $search from list of all available Aggregations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iNkn.png)

Answer (score 0):

[`$search`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/search/) aggregation pipleline stage performs a full-text search of the field or fields in an [**Atlas**](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) collection.

You can only user `$search` in `find` stage.

Checkout this example : [`$search`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68927186/mongodb-full-text-search-with-pymongo-wrong-type-error/68948704#68948704)

Comment: Thank you for your time @YuTing. But, I wanted to know the reason why `$search` stage is missing from list of Aggregations within the MongoDB Compass application.